# Using bootstrap accordion in fancybox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fancybox, fancybox-2, jquery

I just try to have the bootstrap accordion collapse event triggered inside fancy box. But i got no clue how do to that.... Do i have tu use jquery-live? Or...?

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/Content/Image/Facteur/1.jpg">
   <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="~/Content/Image/Facteur/tn/1.jpg">
</a>
<div style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
       simple collapsible
    </button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse in">...</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

        beforeShow: function () {
           this.title = '<div class="myTitle">' + $(this.element).next('div').html() + '</div>';
        },
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            },
            media: {}
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: add an ID to `<div style="display: none;">` and target that ID within your `href` like `href="#mytargetID"`

Comment: Not sure to understand. I can't manage to have a click event triggered by the button inside fancybox. Nothing collapse. And I still need for fancybox to display the jpg. So how does pointing the href to the div can help me?

Comment: Maybe I didn't get. Is the accordion the title of fancybox?

Comment: Any idea? I'm really stuck with this one...

Comment: so, does the answer work? or still stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the issue I see is that you are copying the next `div` into the fancybox `title`. It only copies the element but not its properties (bootstrap accordion functionality) so you have to **[clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** it passing both, its data and events.

Then rename the `ID` of the target (collapsible) element (inside fancybox `title`) to avoid `ID` duplication (with the hidden element) so

try this code :

```
var newTitle;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            // set variable to next div element
            newTitle = $(this.element).next('div')
            // clone it with properties
            .clone(true, true)
            // change ID to avoid ID duplication
            .find("#demo").attr("id", "demo2").end()
            // change the target to new ID
            .find(".btn.btn-danger").attr("data-target", "#demo2").end()
            // show as html
            .html();
            // override fancybox title
            this.title = '<div class="myTitle">' + newTitle + '</div>';
        },
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            },
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ELyqM/)</kbd>